# C# Method returning before event handler is called

Tags: c#, webclient

My uriRead method appears to return before the Asynchronous download is completed, resulting in "" being returned by the method.  If I put a Thread.Sleep(5000) on the "// Wait here?" line it will complete, however.

How can I make this function to wait for the string download to complete and return as soon as it does without entering a static delay?

```
public string uriRead(string uri)
    {
        string result = "";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(AsyncReadCompleted);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri));
        // Wait here?
        return result = downloadedAsyncText;       
    }

    public void AsyncReadCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event Called");
        downloadedAsyncText = e.Result.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(e.Result);
    }
```

Comment: Umm.. do you actually know what Asynchronous means?  Why do it asynchronously if you're just going to wait for it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring.aspx No Async

Comment: Are you trying to write a Windows 8 App?

Comment: This needs to be done asynchronously.  The problem is the method returns before the event handler is called (so downloadedAsyncText is empty), and I'm looking for a way to work around this.

Comment: @mountaineer1980: You're misunderstanding asynchronous. It is *by definition* that the method returns before the event handler is called. This is the entire meaning of asynchronous. If you're waiting for your event handler to fire, you are no longer asynchronous *by definition*.

Comment: @DarkFalcon That is wrong, the method doesn't (always) return before the event handler is called, in fact putting the wait in as the OP did shows that the event handler is called right away. The asynchronous is just that, a non synchronous call. Even if he waits it is still technically asynchronous, though it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @NominSim: Umm, no, if you're waiting for it to complete, it is not asynchronous. "(computing, of a request or a message) allowing the client to continue during processing." http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/asynchronous -- Though I will admit that there are a multitude of definitions for asynchronous.

Comment: @DarkFalcon I get what you are saying, but it is _wrong_ to say that a method has to return before the event handler is called for it to be asynchronous. Think of it this way: if instead of waiting via `Thread.Sleep(5000)` he processed another 100 methods before the return, it would still be asynchronous. The client is continuing during processing, it is performing a `Sleep(5000)` call.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but as other mentioned if you are using Async you should use it properly.
The results are supposed to be read in the `DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler`, you should not wait, this can block your application. Your application need to stay responsive. What if the method never returns?

You need to create a private field in your class `private string results_`  that you set in the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for the result then you want to do it synchronously, not asynchronously as mentioned by others. So use the DownloadString method instead of DownloadStringAsync.

```
public string uriRead(string uri)
{
  WebClient client = new WebClient();
  client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;      
  return client.DownloadString(new Uri(uri));
}
```